# database not working with 2.2,working good with 2.3 and Higher Version

Tags: java, android

my app working on 2.3 and higher version good bt on 2.0 or 2.2 it gives error like "android sqlite returned error code 1 no such table" please help.

Comment: It may be simply becoz of API level although all the class are available since API level one may be other class than SQLite are of higher API that are introduced after API 8 .........do you tried to check the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall the previous application from that android 2.2 version device or emulator and then check again . I think you update your database, so this problem occurs.